# I don't understand a code to load picture in java

Tags: java, opencv, bufferedimage, system.array

I am working with OpenCV in java, but I don't understand part of a class that loads pictures in java:

```
public class ImageProcessor {
  public BufferedImage toBufferedImage(Mat matrix){
    int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
    if ( matrix.channels() > 1 ) {
        type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;
    }
    int bufferSize = matrix.channels()*matrix.cols()*matrix.rows();
    byte [] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    matrix.get(0,0,buffer); // get all the pixels
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(matrix.cols(),matrix.rows(),type);                    
    final byte[] targetPixels = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, targetPixels, 0, buffer.length);  
    return image;
  }
```

Main class sends a `Mat` object to this class.

The result sends `BufferedImage` but I don't understand targetPixels because this class doesn't use it somewhere else. But whenever I comment targetPixels and System.arraycopy, result shows black picture.

I want to know what's `targetPixels` - and what does it do?

Comment: Slightly off-topic: It seems you could optimize the code a lot, by not creating the `buffer` array and skip the `arraycopy`, and instead invoke `matrix.get(0, 0, targetPixels)` directly. Should have exactly the same effect, but eliminates a potential large array allocation and array copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is less about that array, but the methods that get you there.

You start here: [getRaster()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRaster()). That is supposed to return a [WritableRaster](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html) ... and so on.

That class is using from [getDataBuffer()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/Raster.html#getDataBuffer()) from the Raster class; and there we find:

*A class representing a rectangular array of pixels. A Raster encapsulates a DataBuffer that stores the sample values and a SampleModel that describes how to locate a given sample value in a DataBuffer.*

What happens in essence here: that *Image* object, in the end has an array of bytes that are supposed to contain certain information.

That assignment:

```
final byte[] targetPixels = ...
```

retrieves a **reference** to that internal data; and then `arrayCopy()` is used to **copy** data into that array.

For the record: that doesn't look like a good approach - as it **only** works when this copy action *really* affects the internals of that Image object. But what if that last call `getData()` would create a **copy** of the internal data?

In other words: this code tries to gain **direct** access to internal data of some object; and then manipulate that **internal** data.

Even if that works today, it is not robust; and might break easily in the future. The other thing: note that this code does a unconditional cast `(DataBufferByte)`. That code throws a RuntimeException if the the buffer doesn't have exactly that type.

Probably that is "all fine"; since it is all related to "AWT" classes which probably exist for ages; and will not change at all any more. But as said; this code has various potential issues.

Comment: *Even if that works today, it is not robust; and might break easily in the future.* No, it won't. This is well-known, documented behavior, and lots of code depends on this. :-) It **is** possible to do it the other way around though (ie. start with the array, create a `DataBuffer` around it, then wrap it in a `WriteableRaster` and finally create a `BufferedImage` from that and a matching `ColorModel`).

Comment: Another thing: While probably not obvious, there's a direct relationship between the `BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_*` types and `DataBufferByte`. So, the cast is safe, and will always succeed, given the type is always either `TYPE_BYTE_GRAY` or `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR`.

Answer (score 0):

`targetPixels` is the main image data (i.e. the pixels) of your new image.  The actual image is created when the pixeldata is copied from  `buffer` into `targetPixels`.

Answer (score 0):

targetPixels is the array of bytes from your newly created BufferedImage, those bytes are empty thus you need to copy the bytes from the buffer to it with System.arraycopy.. :)